# Weird C code in Bison (yyerror)

Tags: c, bison

I'm using Bison to create a simple parser and have some trouble understanding the C code below. To me it doesn't look like a valid statement, but gcc comepiles it neatly and the code in the block executes on parsing error.

I'd really like to know what this actually means.

The code I refer to is from http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_7.html#SEC66 :

```
yyerror (s) 
     char *s;
{
  // Some code here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K&R_C#KRC)

In modern C (C89/90 or C99) that would be:

```
int yyerror(char *s)
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, seems like we (the younger generation) don't know our roots. :)

Comment: @rickythefox Actually I'm 28 :-)

Answer (score 4):

It means

```
int yyerror(char* s){
  //some code here
}
```

code attached to your question is just another way of specifying function argument types.

Answer (score 3):

This is old [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C#KRC).

Answer (score 1):

*GNU bison* is now at version **2.5**, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/). Why do you use such an ancient version (you refer to bison 1.25 from 1996)?

The  `yyerror` function is for [error recovery](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery). A simple example is [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/html_node/Rpcalc-Error.html#Rpcalc-Error)